# Where is the Django migrations folder?

Tags: django, migration

I must be doing something wrong. Everywhere I see people saying "Look at the migrations folder" but even though I can see migrations there is no folder.

```
Karls-Mac-mini:django_test karl$ tree
├── django_test
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   └── urls.cpython-35.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── manage.py

Karls-Mac-mini:django_test karl$ python manage.py showmigrations
admin
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
 [X] 0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices
auth
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [X] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
 [X] 0008_alter_user_username_max_length
 [X] 0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial
```

Comment: In `some_app/migrations/`. The migrations you see here are however migrations in apps designed by Django itself, so not yours.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Short answer**: the migrations originate from Django apps and third party apps you installed in `INSTALLED_APPS`. Not the ones you defined yourself.

Migrations are generated *per* app, and are stored in `some_app/migrations`.

Even if you do not define migrations for *your* apps, there will usually be migrations that take place, since you (likely) included some apps defined by Django (and other third parties) in your `INSTALLED_APPS`, these have migrations as well.

For example most likely your `INSTALLED_APPS` contains:

```
# settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    'django.contrib.auth',
    # ...
]
```

If we take a look at the [source code of this app <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/tree/stable/2.1.x/django/contrib/auth), we see the `migrations` directiory. By adding this app to the `INSTALLED_APPS` you thus have added apps defined in the Django library itself (or by third parties) to your project, and the migrations of these apps are thus processed in the same way (in fact there is nothing "magical" about these apps, it is more that these handle common problems such that you do not need to care about these anymore).

The `django.contrib.auth` app has a file structure like (ommitting noise):

```
django/
    contrib/
        auth/
             migrations/
                __init__.py
                0001_initial.py
                0002_alter_permission_name_max_length.py
                0003_alter_user_email_max_length.py
                0004_alter_user_username_opts.py
                0005_alter_user_last_login_null.py
                0006_require_contenttypes_0002.py
                0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages.py
                0008_alter_user_username_max_length.py
                0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length.py
```

These are extactly the same migrations you see on the console when you perform migrations for the `auth` app (second section).

Comment: Thank you, that's a great answer. How does Django know these have been executed?

Comment: The history of when and which migrations have been applied is stored in the database table "django_migrations"

Comment: @KarlPenzhorn: it creates an extra table that stores which migrations have been done.

Comment: Isn’t it bad style for a 3rd party app to have migrations? I view migrations for when model schema change and you have an existing database. Why would they need migrations if they at being installed fresh?

Comment: @JasonWirth: because some 3d party apps have their own models. In fact for exampe Django's authentication is a 3rd party app, indeed if you would remove `'django.contrib.auth'` from your `INSTALLED_APPS` immediately, there are no `User`, `Group`s, etc. The migrations are thus used to force Django to create these tables in the database. The fact that there are multiple ones is a result of backwards compatibitility. If you upgrade to the next Django version, and these models were changed, then you can not just create a single migration, since then existing Django apps would break.

Answer (score 4):

Django Project is actually a combination of a few Applications and Configuration files.

Applications and Configuration are actually Python Modules/Packages. Every project has a few default apps installed and they are mentioned in `INSTALLED_APPS` (see project `settings.py`).

These are the default apps and they are not stored/installed in your project: they reside inside Django package by default.

Example:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

For example, `django.contrib.admin` app is used with your application: the `migrations` directory for this app is available at `site-packages/django/contrib/admin/migrations`, but migrations from apps that you created, are all stored inside each app folder.

Comment: Hi! It's quite an old answer, but I feel confused with an interesting question: what if I have several running Django projects which use same default/3rd-party apps? Probably their migrations files will conflict (it can be fixed with virt.envs, but anyway). Also, what if a Python process has not enough rights to write in `site-packages`?